# Convert NSTimeInterval to Days, Hours, Minutes, Seconds

Tags: ios, objective-c, nstimeinterval

I have 2 DATES.

1. End Date
2. Current Date
   Now, I want to find NSTimeInterval and Calculate remaining time in Days, Hours, Minutes, Seconds.
   I do not want to use **NSDateComponents**. 
   I want some formula that calculate that gives remaining time in Days, Hours, Minutes, Seconds.

I tried this below formula but that formula gives  remaining Hours, Minutes, Seconds.

But how do I calculate this Days, Hours, Minutes, Seconds ??

I'm using this below code

```
@property (nonatomic, assign) NSTimeInterval secondsLeft;
_hours = (int)self.secondsLeft / 3600;
_minutes = ((int)self.secondsLeft % 3600) / 60;
_seconds = ((int)self.secondsLeft %3600) % 60;
```

Comment: What is the problem?

Comment: This is a [Does Not Work](http://importblogkit.com/2015/07/does-not-work/) question.  You have not sufficiently described your problem.

Answer (score 4):

Some of your calculations are incorrect. You want:

```
_hours = (int)self.secondsLeft / 3600;
_minutes = (int)self.secondsLeft / 60 % 60;
_seconds = (int)self.secondsLeft % 60;
```

This assumes `_hours`, `_minutes`, and `_seconds` are of type `int` (or some other appropriate integer type).

If you want to format the `NSTimeInterval` into a useful string formatted properly for the user's locale, use `NSDateComponentsFormatter`:

```
NSDateComponentsFormatter *formatter = [[NSDateComponentsFormatter alloc] init];
NSString *result = [formatter stringFromTimeInterval:self.secondsLeft];
```